# Adding column in a datatable with a dynamic column name in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatable

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var dr = dt1.Date; 
String rr = Convert.ToString(dr); 
DataColumn dc1=new DataColumn(); 
dc1.ColumnName = rr; dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
```

And if i add datarow after this like

```
dt.Rows.Add("hello","hello1","hello2");  
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

the data is not displayed in the grid .
If i comment the line

```
dc1.ColumnName = rr;
```

the values are displayed properly 
But i want the colmn name to be the date that is "dt1" here

pleae note that the dt1 are the date values which is dynamic and it will be incremented in each loop.
like

```
dt1 = dt1.AddDays(1);
```

Please help

Comment: Post the xaml for your grid, a sample datatable and an example of how you want your grid to look. Your question is not sufficiently clear as to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your Xaml for the data grid it's difficult to be sure but I imagine that you've specified a field name for the date column in your xaml.

To resolve this, you'll need to set `AutoGenerateColumns=True` and let the grid automatically find the field name.

Comment: already i have given autogenerate column as true...i can display the data ifI DONT USE THIS LINE DataColumn dc1=new DataColumn();

Comment: Post the xaml for your grid.

Comment: <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="615" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,156,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="438" />